# autofac docker dependency issues

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, autofac

I've created a web api project (aspnetcore v2.1.0 packages) with this **csproj configuration**: and **autofac version 4.8.1**

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  <Platform>AnyCPU</Platform>
  <RuntimeIdentifiers>linux-x64;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>
  <GenerateDocumentationFile>true</GenerateDocumentationFile>
</PropertyGroup>
```

I create a publish output with this configuration in my **publishprofile**:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" 
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <ProjectGuid>[SOMEGUID]</ProjectGuid>
    <publishUrl>publish\</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>True</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RuntimeIdentifier>linux-x64</RuntimeIdentifier>
    <SelfContained>False</SelfContained>
    <_IsPortable>false</_IsPortable>
  </PropertyGroup>
 </Project>
```

and this **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./publish/* ./

ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "myapp.dll" ]
```

**Docker version 18.05.0-ce, build f150324**
**Docker Info**

```
 Containers: 23
  Running: 20
  Paused: 0
  Stopped: 3
 Images: 287
 Server Version: 18.05.0-ce
 Storage Driver: overlay2
  Backing Filesystem: extfs
  Supports d_type: true
  Native Overlay Diff: true
 Logging Driver: json-file
 Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
 Plugins:
  Volume: local
  Network: bridge host ipvlan macvlan null overlay
  Log: awslogs fluentd gcplogs gelf journald json-file logentries splunk syslog
 Swarm: inactive
 Runtimes: runc
 Default Runtime: runc
 Init Binary: docker-init
 containerd version: 773c489c9c1b21a6d78b5c538cd395416ec50f88
 runc version: 4fc53a81fb7c994640722ac585fa9ca548971871
 init version: 949e6fa
 Security Options:
  seccomp
   Profile: default
 Kernel Version: 4.9.87-linuxkit-aufs
 Operating System: Docker for Mac
 OSType: linux
 Architecture: x86_64
 CPUs: 4
 Total Memory: 1.952GiB
 Name: linuxkit-025000000001
 ID: 5W3J:Q5U7:AATP:WCCM:MCUY:G2AA:PAGS:XX3I:THTM:FZZF:EAIP:TS2P
 Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
 Debug Mode (client): false
 Debug Mode (server): true
  File Descriptors: 130
  Goroutines: 125
  System Time: 2018-06-08T09:48:01.991499242Z
  EventsListeners: 2
 HTTP Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3128
 HTTPS Proxy: gateway.docker.internal:3129
 Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
 Labels:
 Experimental: true
 Insecure Registries:
  127.0.0.0/8
 Live Restore Enabled: false
```

I also have two files to set the environment variables before startup.
I have a env.list file for docker to set the app specific variables and an equivalent bash script with export commands to set my environment variables on my Mac (to test the application outside of a container).

### Behavior Outside the container

Running below command results in the app starting and accessible.

```
#in the publish folder, starting the app
dotnet myapp.dll
```

### Behavior Inside the container

Running below command results in the error messages shown after the command below.

```
#in the root directory containing the publish folder, the dockerfile 
and the env.list file.
docker build --no-cache -t myapp .
docker run -p 80:80--env-file ./env.list --name myappinstance 
myapp:latest
```

**Errors:**

```
Application startup exception: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = KestrelServer (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.ITransportFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)' on type 'KestrelServer'. ---> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.ITransportFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)' on type 'KestrelServer'. ---> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) (See inner exception for details.) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.CreateServiceContext(IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[6]
      Application startup exception
Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = KestrelServer (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.ITransportFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)' on type 'KestrelServer'. ---> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.ITransportFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)' on type 'KestrelServer'. ---> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) (See inner exception for details.) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.CreateServiceContext(IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

Unhandled Exception: Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An error occurred during the activation of a particular registration. See the inner exception for details. Registration: Activator = KestrelServer (ReflectionActivator), Services = [Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Server.IServer], Lifetime = Autofac.Core.Lifetime.RootScopeLifetime, Sharing = Shared, Ownership = OwnedByLifetimeScope ---> An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.ITransportFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)' on type 'KestrelServer'. ---> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) (See inner exception for details.) (See inner exception for details.) ---> Autofac.Core.DependencyResolutionException: An exception was thrown while invoking the constructor 'Void .ctor(Microsoft.Extensions.Options.IOptions`1[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServerOptions], Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Transport.Abstractions.Internal.ITransportFactory, Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.ILoggerFactory)' on type 'KestrelServer'. ---> Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) (See inner exception for details.) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.IO.Pipelines, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution.  They can only be loaded in the Reflection-only loader context. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131058) ---> System.BadImageFormatException: Cannot load a reference assembly for execution.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.KestrelServer.CreateServiceContext(IOptions`1 options, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
   at lambda_method(Closure , Object[] )
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ConstructorParameterBinding.Instantiate()
   at Autofac.Core.Activators.Reflection.ReflectionActivator.ActivateInstance(IComponentContext context, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Activate(IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Lifetime.LifetimeScope.GetOrCreateAndShare(Guid id, Func`1 creator)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.InstanceLookup.Execute()
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.GetOrCreateInstance(ISharingLifetimeScope currentOperationScope, IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.Core.Resolving.ResolveOperation.Execute(IComponentRegistration registration, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.TryResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters, Object& instance)
   at Autofac.ResolutionExtensions.ResolveService(IComponentContext context, Service service, IEnumerable`1 parameters)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureServer()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token, String shutdownMessage)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.RunAsync(IWebHost host, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostExtensions.Run(IWebHost host)
   at MyApp.Program.Main(String[] args) in Program.cs:line 18
```

It seems like Autofac is missing a dependency. I Don't want to use the SDK image since i dont do the build in the container image itself. I could use the self-containing option to deploy, but i was wondering whether this is normal behavior that for example the dependency System.Pipelines (which autofac needs) is not in the runtime image. Or am i missing something else?

Comment: See my answer on **[System.BadImageFormatException: Reference assemblies should not be loaded for execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61336306/system-badimageformatexception-reference-assemblies-should-not-be-loaded-for-ex/61702386#61702386)**.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't use a pre-installed SDK and you don't allow the image to download what it needs on the fly (build) then you have to publish a self-contained app to ensure everything including all dependencies makes it to the image.